# DL320e Compatibility with a StorageWorks disk array

Tags: linux, storage, scsi

I currently have a HPE DL320e Gen8 V2.  I'd like to expand the storage capabilities for the system as it is being used as a lab NFS system.  My question is, since I am not extremely versed in hardware, could I add the following PCIe card (https://shorturl.at/qJUY0) and attach a HP 335921-B21 StorageWorks Modular Smart Array 20 Hard drive array (https://shorturl.at/eqtBQ)?  I am running Rocky Linux 9 on the server currently...if the connection is possible, how would the disks in the array be exposed to Rocky?  Thanks you in advance for putting up with a newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use that combination today. It's first-generation 1.5Gbps SATA and requires antiquated U320 SCSI connections.

You'd be better off with a more modern JBOD unit or use larger internal drives on the existing server.